# Could not find json-1.8.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rubygems, unicorn, digital-ocean

I deploy my app on digitalocean and doen all configuration chagnes. When I access its url it gives an error

```
504 Gateway Time-out
```

Error in unicorn.log is

```
E, [2016-11-21T07:58:42.365353 #3882] ERROR -- : Could not find json-1.8.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
```

Error in nginx is

```
*17 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 151.241.230.107, server: _, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "www.dynaforwardclassifiedsbooster.com"
```

Comment: try bundle install on the server

Comment: install  gem manually like  gem install json -v '1.8.2'

Comment: that also done....

Comment: I udpate my question  add nginx error also

Comment: update your bundler  like 'gem update bundler'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128629/discussion-between-pratap-and-haseeb-ahmad).